# JPlayer Multiple Playlist

Tags: jplayer, playlist

I want to know about how can i achieve to create multiple playlists using jplayer?

e.g the user will be able to add songs to a playlist and he will be able to the playlist so that whenever he visit the website, he don't need to create the same playlist over and over again.

and i have a working jplayer playlist. just that i need to know how to save that player.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this. Using the video player as a second audio player
http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-multi/

Comment: Thanks for contributing to Stack Overflow.  Please also summarize or provide the relevant information from the link you provided in case that site goes down, is edited, etc.